# Is there a reason tuples, structs, and tuple structs need to have inconsistent syntax in Rust?

Tags: syntax, rust

Is there a reason tuples, structs, and tuple structs need to have inconsistent syntax in Rust?

I'm still reading the manual, so there may be an obvious answer to this, but couldn't the syntax be unified so that all of the following are legal?:

```
struct { Int, Int }
struct Foo { Int, Int }
struct { a: Int, b: Int }
struct Foo { a: int, b: Int }
struct Foo { Int, a: Int, b: Int, Int }
```

If there is some technical reason to avoid mixing named and unnamed parameters, you could keep the unnamed parameters in the `()` and named parameters in the `{}`...

```
struct (Int, Int);
struct Foo(Int, Int);
struct { a: Int, b: Int }
struct Foo { a: Int, b: Int }
struct Foo(Int, Int) { a: Int, b: Int }
```

Comment: Does Rust have any look-ahead limitations like Go does? Go syntax is quite influenced by the one-token-look-ahead rule; this could explain an "*actual* limitation" - As far as mixing Tuples (ordinal elements) / Records (named elements) .. most languages do not have such hybrid, where the "*design* limitation" is it is not a supported construct.

Comment: What would `struct (Int, Int)` do? It doesn't really make sense to declare an unnamed type.

Comment: It's probably *possible*, but why would you want to unify structs and tuples ? They are different objects serving different purposes.

Comment: Really, you could remove tuples and tuple structs from the language with little fallout, though you’d want convenience syntax for anonymous structs to reduce pain, like `struct { a: A, b: B }` instead of `(A, B)` (e.g. `fn a() -> struct { a: A, b: B }`).

Comment: @Levans, I'm more or less asking what the difference is.  There is a significant cognitive load to having three constructs instead of one, so there is probably a good reason they designed the language this way...  i.e. perhaps they are implemented differently by the compiler...

Comment: @dbaupp, unnamed types (and functions for that matter) are useful in expressions.  It would be kinda like a literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but none of the alternative proposals seemed worth breaking all existing code.

https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/unify-structs-tuples-and-funciton-calls/1667